# Invalid Parameter Number:number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: mysql, yii, dataprovider

```
 $dataProvider=$model->search();

 $dataProvider->criteria->addcondition('company_code= :id')->params=array(':id' => $company);

 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'tblapptcodegrid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'filter'=>$model,
```

The data is displayed correctly, but when i try to search in filter; it comes with the error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tblapptcode` `t` WHERE (appt_code LIKE :ycp0) AND (company_code= :id) (C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:543)
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$dataProvider->criteria->addcondition('company_code= :id')->params[':id'] = $company;
```

Comment: Could you please give a reason as to why this works as opposed to the one in question..